# fglrx Radeon HD 4550 xorg.conf tweaks 2D performance

Tags: compiz

I am having horrible problems with my 2D performance on my Radeon HD 4550 using the fglrx driver(the open source is somewhat better, but I need fglrx support for 3D).

It has established a xorg.conf file in the system, and there is hardly anything in there. So I was wondering if there are any tweaks I can apply to it, to boost 2D, and potentially even 3D performance higher.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have an mobility radeon hd 4650, in xorg.conf, section device :

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "RenderAccel" "true"
    Option      "AllowGLXWithComposite" "true"
EndSection
```

In section "Screen" I put

```
   Option      "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
```

Try this, and see if something works better ...

when I run `glxgears`:

```
34947 frames in 5.0 seconds = 6989.268 FPS
```

good luck